# mysql error "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"

Tags: mysql, command-line, command-line-interface

I am having problem accessing my database,

when I try to run `mysql -h localhost -u root -p`
and enter the password

I am recieving this kind of error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Wonder why I get this.

When I type `mysql --version`

I have no error and got this msg: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.22, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2`

But when I type this comman `mysql -v` I got an error that says:

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

I thought `mysql --version` and `mysql -v` are desame

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: -v, --verbose       Write more information. -V, --version       Output version information and exit.
So you had a lower case v and had to had a capital V to make the statement: "mysql --version and mysql -v are desame"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get that error when the MySQL service isn't running.  What OS are you on?  I'm on Debian GNU/Linux, so I start the service with

```
# service mysql start
```

but other systems may use something different, like `start` or `invoke-rc.d` or something.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I run that code and got this message `start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.52" (uid=1000 pid=18021 comm="start mysql ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")` any idea?

Comment: Have a look at some of the posts here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1469902&page=2
One suggestion from there: have you run out of disk space?

Comment: Nope I check my disk space and it is only about 40%.

Comment: First, check to be sure that the service is actually not running (`ps -ef | grep mysql` should do it, but also check if that socket exists).  If it isn't running, then that's the answer to this question, and you need to figure out why it isn't starting.  If it is already running, then there is indeed a problem to solve here.

Comment: It is running but, the socket is not there. in `/var/run/mysqld/` directory there is no `mysqld.sock`. How do I recover or generate the mysqld.sock?... Thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11348/discussion-between-lxop-and-king-pangilinan)